# how to send js library to client dynamically?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, dynamic-library

I have a string variable that contains some JavaScript codes.

I want to send these codes to client as a JavaScript file attached!
just like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/some.js"></script>
```

but this `some.js` file is not exist on the server!

how can I do this in ASP.net MVC3?

Comment: You need to reference the location of the file - either a relative URL if it's somewhere in the site, or a fully qualified URL if it resides someplace else.  Note that you could run into some cross-domain scripting issues depending on what you ultimately intend to do with the JavaScript.

Comment: Where is the some.js file? can you be more especific? @Tim has right in his comment. Maybe your script is located in... http://www.example.com/js/some.js

Answer (score 0):

You can add your string variable to your model ("MyJavascriptCode"), then simply output the contents inside a script tag on your view. Html.Raw outputs content with encoding it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     @Html.Raw(Model.MyJavascriptCode)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To call from a tag script, you can create an action that returns a JavaScriptResult

```
public JavaScriptResult GetSomeScript()
{
      var script = LoadFromSomeWhere();
      return JavaScript(script);
}
```

Check this out: http://forums.asp.net/t/1716356.aspx